# Is it possible to use USB print server with LPT printer using LPT/USB adapter?

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, printer, lpt

I would like to share my old Laserjet 6P printer (LPT only) in home network. The printer is really old but still working well and enough for our needs.

However I do not want to buy LPT print server as it is more difficult to buy any and in case of printer "death" I will have useless print server.

I would buy and wifi usb print server - box, where you connect a usb printer and it directly shares it using built in wifi.

However I am not sure if I can use my printer with so called *USB to DB25 Female Port Print Converter Cable LPT* which I can have from Ebay for less than 4 USD and connect it to the usb print server. It would be nice solution but I am not sure if the adapter converts the device into a full-featured usb printer.

What do you think? Would it work?

thanks

Comment: do you have a computer that is generally always powered on? if so, plug it and install it to that computer and make it shared over the network.

Comment: no, I want to replace a desktop PC with printer - which is currently "shared" - everyone can go there and print - with a small box - print server.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the brand & model.  Some USB-parallel adapters have drivers only for older versions of Windows.  You haven't specified what brand you're referring to.

You might want to check Amazon as an alternative.  (Note, I have no connection with them.)  At least then you could know what brand you're buying.  I very much doubt that a $4 adapter would have current drivers, i.e. for Win7, since those usually go for about $20-25.

I have used one with Win7 but, as mentioned, it costs more. I see that Cables2Go makes some that are Win7-compatible, but there are also other brands.

Comment: Hi, I use such $4 adapter both with W7 and linux and no driver was needed but I do not want to pay about $80 for usb print server and realize that it does not work. I see potential problem with the print server firmware...